# How do I display text that will vary (in Xcode with Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I just started with swift and Xcode and have been working on an app. Right I have no idea how to print a variable in the UI. I understand how to use Labels for static text but need to print numbers that are going to vary based on user input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to create strings from numbers. Then assign to your label.

```
var myNum: Int = 5
var myString = "The number is \(myNum)"
myLabel.text = myString
```

Comment: You can also cast the numbers: myLabel.text = String(myNum)

Comment: @mcclux, your code is correct, but it's not casting. In the context of Swing you should use the "as" operator to cast. Here you are creating a new String object with an init that accepts a number as parameter. (Nitpick.)

Comment: I want to view large amounts of scrollable text of a json parsed variable. How can I do that?